# non-rectangle blocks with fixed background attachment

Tags: html, css, svg

The problem is: v-typed bottom, as [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyxdQ.png). I need to trim corners of the block leaving the fixed background (background-attachment: fixed) so it stays scrollable and visible through the v-bottom. Also, the angle must be fixed in every same block (the svg mask doesn't help me because of it's scalable nature). The heights of blocks is different.

For few days I'm trying to deal with this problem... can anyone help?...

PS: both blocks at the screenshot (the yellow and the dark) differs only with it's content and background image so they both have theese v-typed triangular bottoms with fixed background.

Edit: crossbrowser support is needed.

Comment: HTML or jsfiddle would be better?

Comment: jsfiddle with only few same blocks and different backgrounds

Answer (score 0):

I tried with `clip-path: polygon(0 0,100% 0,100% 80%,50% 100%,0 80%);`
the only problem is that you cant say 60px from bottom.

here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HXfGM/)

Comment: but I can use js or jq and calculate it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Forget to ask... and what about firefox, mobile browsers and IE?

Comment: oh.. jeah sry the support for this is still quite limited, i think it only works in chrome and mobile chrome. but i dont know any other way to get this effect.

Answer (score 0):

I would attack this problem with three div's. The outermost has the dark/black background.

The next one contains the yellow background. It can be a child of the outermost one.

Then I'd create a transparent PNG with the V shape and put that on top of the inner (yellow) div. If you position that div at the bottom of the inner/yellow div, it will look as if it vanishes inside of the background.